# How to add several tagged values in a drop down list in enterprise architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using enterprise architect and I want to have several values displayed in a drop down list as tagged values. I am only able to give one value to the tagged value but I don't know how to do it for a list of choices. I could not find help in the userguide by sparx systems. Maybe I did not find it...any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

To create a list of drop down tagged values in [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com):

1. Open the Tagged Values Dockable Window [View | Tagged Values] (Ctrl + Shift +6)
2. Click "Default Tagged Value Types" button on the Tagged Values window.
3. This will open the UML Types Dialog.
4. Browse to the Tagged Value Types Tab (should be open by default)
5. Enter in the name for your new tagged value
6. In the detail enter the following:

Type=Enum;
Values=Val1,Val2,Val3;
Default=Val2;

7.(Where the vals are your drop down options)

8.Click Save and Close the UML Types Dialog

To access this new drop down tagged value click "New Tagged Value" and select your tag from the list and click OK. Your drop down options will now be available in the Tagged Values window.

You can find a list of all the different tag value type commands [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/modeling_languages/predefinedtaggedvaluetypes.html)

I hope this helps.