# EA Script for Defined Tag Types

Tags: automation, enterprise-architect

I would like to create an EA Script to configure (add/edit/delete) the Defined Tag Types (Settings > UML Types > Tagged Value Types) similar to what is done manually [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6514593/809623).

I did not found any useful information about the object storing the Defined Tag Types. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration is not available in EA's API. If you want to make changes to it programmatically, you'll have to manipulate the project database directly.

The "Tagged Value Types" are stored in the `t_propertytypes` table. Please note that tagged value types defined in an MDG Technology are not listed here, this table only contains those that are shown in the "UML Types" dialog.

Comment: Hmm...that's too bad. I guess I need to do it manually and set it right from the first time making the master EAP file (I'm using distributed deployment).

Comment: You can also create an MDG Technology which holds both the tagged value types and the stereotypes which are supposed to have the tagged values; this MDG Technology can then be made available to any number of projects. In conjunction with your other question regarding tagging of elements on creation, I believe this is a better fit for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that you can programmatically only read the Tagged Values and change their value. Apparently you cannot add/remove Tagged Values.

Here is a part of the corresponding API. To add/remove a tagged value, you have to go directly to the DB.

TaggedValue Methods:

Method
 Type
 Notes

GetAttribute(string propName)
 String
 Returns the text of a single named property within a structured Tagged Value.

Parameters:

· propName: String - the name of the property for which the text is being returned

GetLastError()
 String
 Returns a string value describing the most recent error that occurred in relation to this object.

HasAttributes()
 Boolean
 Returns true if the Tagged Value is a structured Tagged Value with one or more properties.

SetAttribute(
string propName, 
string propValue)
 Boolean
 Sets the text of a single named property within a structured Tagged Value.

Parameters:

· propName: String -  - the name of the property for which the text is being set

· propValue: the value of the property

Update()
 Boolean
 Updates the current TaggedValue object after modification or appending a new item.

If false is returned, check the GetLastError function for more information.

Comment: Downvoted. This has got nothing to do with the tagged value types the question is about; the assertion that you can't add/remove tagged values is also wrong.